# How do you enable “bootable” on MacBook?

Tags: macos, terminal, mac, hard-drive, applications

12” MacBook (Early 2016) Model: 1534 EMC 2991

I’m trying to use a USB to use a software on a MacBook that won’t boot. I’ve been doing everything from recovery mode.

Everything is fine with the USB it’s journaled, guid, writable, except one thing, and that’s bootable. It says “no” for it. How would I go about enabling this setting?

Is there a command in terminal to help me enable this setting?

Thanks.

[image]

Edit: and also for some reason when I hit “option” when I boot, I only see the option to boot into internet recovery mode it wont give me the choice to select my usb. Am I doing something wrong?

Edit #2: so when I try downloading something I get his message that my SSD is full and this could be the reason why it won’t mount. Does anyone know how to free up space on it? Erasing won’t work.
[image]

Comment: Two things. First your mount point suggests that the drive is mounted with ParagonFS, which could be a problem. How was the volume formatted? Hopefully with the native macOS Disk Utility.app? And TWO, how was macOS installed on this volume? normally one would boot from an installer (these days usually a USB key) and point the installer to your target of choice. At *that* point I would reformat the target as MacOS Extended (journaled) and proceed with the installation. **THAT** would make it bootable.

Comment: @SteveChambers It is in GPT, and it is formatted in Apple HFS. I installed the paragon program on the drive on a windows computer with the Mac version of paragon, I used Balena Etcher. The SSD on my Mac won’t mount after erasing it with APFS in the beginning. Ultimately that is what created this mess, and I am left with a folder and question mark icon upon boot. I planned to use the paragon program using the usb in order to repair the drive that Apple’s services can’t. I pretty much have no clue on how to go about this.

Comment: @SteveChambers I also used a USB to install macOS Catalina on and the installation process was working up until the Apple logo and the bar being stuck at 24% came. I was then prompted once again with a flashing folder and a question mark.

Comment: Add the model of Mac you are doing this on to your original question. Also have  you tried Recovery Mode? If you get similar results with recovery mode you may have a failing SSD. I have *heard* that there are utilities that can make a bootable USB on Windows from a macOS installer. We have also had people try that here with mixed results. So that might be a rabbit hole you don't want to go down. I guess it depends on your happiness with troubleshooting a problem with a Windows utility making a Mac installer.